# Showing that $\lim_n \sum_{k = 0}^n a_{kn} \lambda_1(A_{kn}) = \int_a^b f d\lambda$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I need some help with the following:

(i) Show that $\chi_{\mathbb Q \cap [a,b]}$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)|_{[a,b]}$ and compute $\int \chi_{\mathbb Q \cap [a,b]} d\lambda$.

(ii) Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be measurable with respect to $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)|_{[a,b]}$ and be bounded. Assume that $f([a,b]) \subset [0,1)$. Define $A_{kn} := \{x \in [a,b]; \frac{k}{n} \le f(x) < \frac{k+1}{n}\}$, $0 \le k \le n-1$. Show that $A_{kn}$ is measurable.

(iii) Let $k/n \le a_{kn} < \frac{k+1}{n}$ be given and let $L_n(f) = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_{kn} \lambda_1(A_{kn})$. Show that $\lim_n L_n(f) = \int_a^b f d\lambda$.

I have done (i) and (ii), with the result that $\int \chi_{\mathbb Q \cap [a,b]} d\lambda$ is zero. I have some trouble to show (iii). 
I have already shown that $[a,b] = \bigcup_{k = 0}^{n-1} A_{kn}$ and this union is disjoint. I have also shown that $\varphi_n := \sum_{k = 0}^n a_{kn} \chi_{A_{kn}}$ converges on $[a,b]$ pointwise to $f$. 
I know that $|L_n(f) - \int_a^b f \, \mathrm d\lambda_1| \le \int |f- \varphi_n| d\lambda$ but I cannot put the limit inside the integral, right?

I also do not see how I can use (i). We did not have any convergent theorems like Dominated convergence and the like.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it's a simple function, also for simple functions integrals are sums.